# jQuery how to set add a fields to a form without having to hardcode input field?

Tags: jquery

I have some divs that have a data attribute that I would like be sent as parameteres with a form. How do I add this data? One solution is to write add a hidden form field to the form and then set the value with jQuery, but is that really necessary?

Code:

```
<div data-name="egon"></div>

<form action="/some-url">
<input type="text" value="" name="user[age]" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Example assign data name to form:

```
$("div").click(function(){
 // Add data-name to form as the parameter user[name]
});
```

1 solution but it is awful if you have many divs..

```
    <div data-name="egon"></div>

    <form action="/some-url">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="user[name]" id="username" />
    <input type="text" value="" name="user[age]" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

$("div").click(function(){
 $("#username").val($("div").data('name');
});
```

I know my example is terrible.

Comment: What html are you using for this? jQuery can create the `input` to send (quite easily), but there may be a better option.

Comment: Show your code, we're not mind readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use you div custom attribute like this:

```
// this is div with custom attribute
<div class='demo' mydata='welcome!!'>Welcome</div>

// now I want to get div attribute value then you can try
$(function () {
    var divText = $('.demo').attr('mydata');
    alert(divText);
});
```

I hope you understand :) Good luck!!!